# Error in Array execution in foreach loop :

Tags: php

Someone please help me correcting the errors in this code
This was the code where i am trying to find the names of the icecreams in stock

```
<?php
$flavors = array();
$flavors[]=array("name" => "CD" , "in_stock" => true);
$flavors[]=array("name" => "V"  , "in_stock" => true);
$flavors[]=array("name" => "S"  , "in_stock" => false);

foreach($flavors as $flavor => $value) {
if($flavor["in_stock"] == true) {
    echo $flavor["name"] . "\n";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have flat non-associative array, that means  you don't need to iterate using `$key => $value` but just `$item`.

So in you case the fix is that simple:

https://ideone.com/j7RMAH

```
...
// foreach ($flavors as $flavor => $value) {
foreach ($flavors as $flavor) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> **[foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)** - `foreach` will additionally assign the current element's key to the `$key` variable on each iteration

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

**Note:** ***You can use any variable it's not necessary to use the variable with name `$key`***

You are using the key for the condition `$flavor["in_stock"]` and same for the `$flavor["name"]`. You need to use `$value` which holding the current iteration `array`, correct use of `foreach` for your code is

```
foreach($flavors as $flavor => $value) {
  if($value["in_stock"] == true) {
    echo $value["name"] . "\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why iterate at all? One can just filter an array with a condition:

```
<?php

$flavors = [];
$flavors[] = ['name' => 'CD', 'in_stock' => true];
$flavors[] = ['name' => 'V',  'in_stock' => true];
$flavors[] = ['name' => 'S',  'in_stock' => false];

$inStock = array_filter($flavors, function (array $flavor) {
    return $flavor['in_stock'];
});

print_r($inStock);

$inStockFlavors = array_column($inStock, 'name');

print_r($inStockFlavors);
```